# Is there another way to log in to Stack Overflow without using a social media account?

Tags: support, login, openid

Is there a possibility for a login without using Facebook, Yahoo, Google, AOL, [LiveJournal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiveJournal), etc.?

My company has strict intranet rules where you cannot use social media or private emails.

Before when I needed to post a question, I created an association with Verisign Authentication to log in and post a question on the Stack Overflow sites, since such authentication is not classified as social media/private email.

But the Verisign Authentication support was removed some time ago (I think maybe 2015).

Is there another workaround for this?

Comment: Are you saying that the `yourid.pip.verisignlabs.com` OpenID URL no longer works for you? I log in with a custom  OpenID URL myself, with no issues (mine is backed by the Stack Exchange OpenID provider via delegation).

Comment: The Verisign OpenID *icon* may have been removed but you can still simply enter the OpenID URL into the login form. Click on ‘more login options’ to reveal the OpenID box, and type in `yourid.pip.verisignlabs.com` URL (see https://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/introducing-verisign-personal-identity-provider-pip).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can set up an email/password combo. [The instructions for doing so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704/155160) are unfortunately complicated at the moment, but still doable.

You can also try this, which is somewhat simpler:

There are two email credentials on your account (presumably associated with the Facebook/Google credentials), and you can use either of them to set up a password and keep logging in that way. To do so, go to the [account recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) page and enter whichever of the email addresses that you want to use. In the recovery email you get, there should be the following sentence:

> This email address is associated with an account, but no password is associated with it yet, so it can't be used to log in. If you initiated this request, click this link to set a password.

Click that link. You should arrive at a page where you can set up a password and that will be associated with your account. (I do recommend opening the link in a browser where you're already logged in to SO.)

Comment: The procedure you link to is only applicable if the user already has a Stack Exchange OpenID account.  The OP does not, all they need the do is either add one, or just use their Verisign OpenID.

Comment: I think the question was caused by the OpenID box having been hidden on the login form.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The procedure should still work - ultimately it just relies on abusing account recovery. But this reminds me that there is an easier way. I'll update my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use *any valid OpenID provider*. The Social Media sites listed on the login form are not the only ones allowed.

When you log in, click the *more login options* link next to the login button, and enter your OpenID URL in the box provided.

Unfortunately, the Verisign ID project shut down entirely, but when they were operational their OpenID URL was in the form of `yourid.pip.verisignlabs.com` (with `yourid` replaced with your personal id).

Do make sure you have [first registered your OpenID account with your Stack Overflow account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers).

Comment: Verisign shut down their OpenID service entirely in September 2016. Existing credentials are unusable now.

Comment: @AdamLear bah, didn’t know that.